# Python Http запрос к proxmox на клонирование виртуальной машины

Tags: python, http, requests, proxmox

в документации указано следующее:
HTTP:       POST /api2/json/nodes/{node}/qemu/{vmid}/clone

Параметры:

```
___________________________________
|name:  | Type:    |  Format:      |
|-------|----------|---------------|
|new    | Integer  | <integer>(1-N)|
|node   | String   | <string>      |
|vmid   | Integer  | <integer>(1-N)|
------------------------------------
```

вот ссылка на оригинал: 
https://pve.proxmox.com/pve-docs/api-viewer/index.html
путь: nodes/{node}/qemu/{vmid}/clone

Параметры "node" и "vmid" передаются в link, а вот как передать параметр "newid"? Понять не могу.
Вот пример моего запроса:
requests.post('https://%s:%s/api2/json/nodes/%s/qemu/%s/clone' %(ip, port, nodes, lxcID), headers=headers, cookies=cookies, verify=False)
куда в нем вставить "newid"?
для работы с запросами используется библиотека "requests"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример:

```
url = f"https://{ip}:{port}/api2/json/nodes/{node}/qemu/{lxcID}/clone"
params = dict(newid=12345)

r = requests.post(url, params=params)
```